# PDFKit text align justify not working well with continued: true

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit

I'm working on a project using Nodejs and PDFKit and I need to write a text with bold and normal fonts at the same line(I'm making a service contract). I used this code to do it

```
 doc.font(fontArial).fontSize(10)
    doc.text(' ')
    doc.text(`Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and `, {
        align: 'justify',
        width: doc.page.width - (doc.page.margins.left + doc.page.margins.right),
        continued: true
    }).font(fontArialBold).text(`typesetting industry.`, {
        continued: true
    }).font(fontArial).text(` Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.`, {
        continued: true
    })
```

This is the result:
[PDF Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQmZC.png)

What it should do? The text need to be properly justified. How can I do it?

I tried to use other libs, but i had the same problems with them.